# The tag wiki for resource recommendations contradicts existing tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, resource-recommendation

The [tag wiki](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/resource-recommendations/info) for [reference-request](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) contains the following sentences:

> Contrast this with the [reference-request](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag, which is for questions that ask for a specific resource, instead of any resource explaining a particular topic. The tags [resource-recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations) and [reference-request](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) are 
>   mutually exclusive; they should never both be applied to the same question.

However, [reference-request](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) is a tag synonym for [resource-recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations).

Comment: Tip: To point out non-controversial issues, typos, etc, it is preferred to first mention this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) (as opposed to meta).

Comment: @Qmechanic: Point taken. To excuse myself: I am mostly on Stack Exchanges, which do not use their chat very much.

Comment: No need to excuse. Besides, the above comment is meant as a tip to everyone.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5281/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch. I submitted an edit replacing [reference-request](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) with [specific-reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-reference).